How to fix VSCode autoupdate?
I have VSCode installed from the MS Store. It has been auto updating for some time but recently it stops doing so. It still checks for the updates and warn me about new version, but when I click to download new version it just downloads a zip file instead of updating itself.
I checked the in MS Store and there is no button to update, the button says "installed" and disabled (no open available).
I am not sure where even start investigating the problem, can you suggest me what to do in order to restore autoupdate functionality?
Help>About
Commit: eaa41d57266683296de7d118f574d0c2652e1fc4
Date: 2024-08-07T20:16:39.455Z
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.22631


IMHO you'd better go to https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues, check if there is a similar issue already or else create a new one.
